# Проблема с доступом к файлу

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
file = open('home/pi/yandex.txt', 'r')
html = file.read()
file.close () 
print (html)
with open ("history.txt") as h:
    lines = h.readlines()
for line in lines:
     words = line.split()
for word in words:
     print (word)
```

Добавил текстовой файл в основную директорию моего ммини-компьютера, запустил прогу через интерпретатор, вот что выдаёт:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "htmlreader.py", line 2, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/pi/yandex.txt'
```

Подскажите, почему так, и как это исправить?

Comment: Слеш в начале пути не забыли?

Comment: Нет, всё равно не помогает

Comment: У вас не находит данный файл или директорию. Попробуйте создать папки /home/pi и внутри них yandex.txt

Также попробуйте написать следующий путь - ./home/pi/yandex.txt
(Кстати, вот тут тоже ошибка - with open ("history.txt") as h ,забыли указать mode)

Comment: Ой, спасибо... И правда заработало, когда я создал эти папки.  A что Вы говорили про mode?